# Where are the other schools of magic beyond the seven already named?

Tags: harry-potter, names

With the new [Pottermore site](https://www.pottermore.com/) and the upcoming release of [Fantastic Beasts](http://www.fantasticbeasts.com/) film, JK Rowling has been awesome and given us new writing on the [schools of magic in the world](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wizarding-schools).

In the introduction it is stated that there are **eleven** established/registered schools. There are writings for six of them. I don't think we need a new writing for Hogwarts... so that means **seven** have been located and defined.

1. Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry - Great Britain
2. [Beauxbatons Academy of Magic](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/beauxbatons-academy-of-magic) - France
3. [Durmstrang Institute](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/durmstrang-institute) - Northern Europe (possibly Estonia, Latvia, or Belarus)
4. [Mahoutokoro](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/mahoutokoro) - Japan
5. [Uagadou](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/uagadou) - Africa (possibly Congo/DRC)
6. [Castelbruxo](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/castelobruxo) - Brazil
7. [Ilvermorny](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ilvermorny) - United States

Do we know anything of possible location or names of the other four schools? I know *Koldovstoretz* was mentioned as school in Russia, but is that still canon?

8. Koldovstoretz - Russia (maybe depending on current canon)

The final three are my guesses based on the population and geography on the world.

9. Name Unknown - China (based on population)
10. Name Unknown - India (based on population)
11. Name Unknown - Australia (based on geography)

Related:  [Are there wizarding schools in the rest of the "magical" world?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13575/are-there-wizarding-schools-in-the-rest-of-the-magical-world)

Comment: I have a feeling that this is a duplicate. I'll keep looking.

Comment: What about the school in Salem, MA, USA?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13575/are-there-wizarding-schools-in-the-rest-of-the-magical-world

Comment: Koldovstoretz was mentioned in *Book of Potions*. Pretty sure that's canon.

Comment: @Escoce tweet from June 2015 says it is not a real school. https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/607275327111458816

Comment: I always imagined Durmstrang to be Scandinavian in its location. But maybe that is just me.

Comment: @skooba - I disagree. Alexwlchan's answer on the dupe explicitly references the *known* schools. If the question was "where do we think they might be" I could see an argument for VTC 'Opinion-based'

Comment: @Richard changed the title if it helps. I feel one day this question will have a canon answer... but that may not be for a long.

Comment: @skooba - Still a dupe. Also now  borderline VTC "Future works"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### One is in Russia (Koldovstoretz)

- This was first revealed in the Pottermore tie-in *Book of Potions* which Rowling had written the story for. In that game there is a Potions Tournament attended by four magical schools, including the Koldovstoretz, which was said to be from Russia. (This game is also the first canonical appearance of Uagadou.)

  > Step forth, my would-be potioneer, let's see what awaits us next! Our champion from **Koldovstoretz, the Russian school of Witchcraft and Wizardry** has reached the battlefield first and is attempting to cross ...
  >
  > (...)
  >
  > Our champion from **Koldovstoretz school in Russia** has been waylaid by the Red Caps. This brings Hogwarts into third place, but Koldovstoretz will soon be catching up!
  >
  > <sub>[Book of Potions](https://pastebin.com/jzWbnsUh)</sub>

  In 2014, Nick Blackford had prepared some Pottermore fact lists for the Bloomsbury Children editions, and mistakenly included a few facts from unreleased writings.

  > Students from the **Russian wizarding school, Koldovstoretz**, play a version of Quidditch where they fly on entire, uprooted trees instead of broomsticks.
  >
  > <sub>[Pottermore fact file from 2014 UK children's edition of *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*](http://nickblackford.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/book7-1-2.png)</sub>

### One is in Australia.

- When Pottermore released a bunch of the Wizarding School writings in January 2016, it was implied that their plan was to release the rest later (whenever Pottermore needed another traffic boost).

  The writings were first "unveiled" at HP Celebration 2016, where Evanna Lynch read three of them outloud. However, whoever wrote her introduction speech didn't seem to be aware that only some of the writings were being released.

  > What if I told you that there are Wizarding Schools in Africa, Brazil, **Australia**, **Russia**, and other secret locations? So this evening, for the very first time, I have the pleasure of reading to you brand new details about some of these Wizarding Schools.
  >   <sub>[Evanna Lynch — HP Celebration 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SzgNaIV3_4)</sub>

  Rowling also seemed to imply the same on twitter, when she was replying to tweets about the newly released writings.

  > **where do aussie wizards go?**
  >
  > **J.K. Rowling:** *That information will be revealed in due course!*
  >   <sub>[Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/693385141306130432)</sub>

### One *might* be in Canada

- Another of Rowling's tweets seemed to imply that there was a Canadian school as well.

  > **What is the Canadian school of witchcraft and wizardry? I feel like Canadians are always left out**
  >
  > **J.K. Rowling:** *Keep watching @Pottermore...*
  >   <sub>[Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/693525181810249728)</sub>

  However, this may have just been referring to the Ilvermorny school, which hadn't yet been revealed at the time.

### There is no information available about the final "missing" school.

---

**Tl;dr:** 1)Russia, 2)Australia, 3)maybe Canada, 4)don't know

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to put the **TLDR** on top.

Comment: @SQB - The tldr isn't really even necessary here, and you can get the same info from just skimming the headers.