# What happens to the Muggle-born students from the area of Durmstrang Institute?

Tags: harry-potter

If Durmstrang Institute doesn't accept Muggle-born students, where are Muggle-born wizards/witches from the area supposed to study then? Do they don't go to school at all and don't learn magic?

Comment: Are you sure Durmstrang doesn't accept Muggle-born students? I don't remember that.

Comment: @Randal'Thor A bit of Googling indicates that GoF Ch 11 has a line where somebody says it was *rumored* Durmstrang didn't accept muggle-borns. I don't have the full text at hand, so I can't say more than that.

Comment: From Harry Potter wiki  - "Durmstrang does not admit Muggle-borns, but certain students may not necessarily share this prejudice".

Comment: I think Malfoy brags about it on the train

Comment: ah yes Malfoy, the paragon of truth and accuracy

Comment: Who's to say Durmstrang is the only school of magic in that area?

Answer (score -2):

The area of Durmstrang is Bulgaria. I expect every country has a magical school because Quidditch World Cup is played between countries and not between schools and those players need to learn playing somewhere.

So they either go to one of the neighbour Balkan countries, (transportation is not a big problem for wizards) , or Bulgaria has a secondary school that accepts muggle-borns.

I think the second one makes more sense.

Comment: There are, canonically, [11 'major' wizarding schools in the world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/97236/20774). Durmstrang seems to serve a considerable areas including (but not restricted to) Bulgaria

Comment: Yep, I missed that. But a secondary school goes well with not being a long lived and prestigious school, hence “major”. I think those 11 are magical world’s ivy league.